# Is there a security hole in this method to protect Jquery/AJAX requests with PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, security, access-control

On my `search.php` page, where users can search things by city/location, the search is made via JQuery/AJAX to a page called `search_data.php`, with the results being returned on `search.php`.

Now this is what I'm doing:
On `search.php` I have this:

```
$_SESSION['verid'] = randomid(12);
$_SESSION['verkey'] == randomid(12);
```

`randomid` is a function that generates 12 random characters. These two session variables are sent along with the jquery `$.post` request as javascript variables (named "vuid" and "vukid")

On `search_data.php` I have this:

```
if ($_POST['vuid'] != $_SESSION['verid']) {
    header('Location: http://mysite.com/');
    die();
} else {
if ($_POST['vukid'] != $_SESSION['verkey']) {
    header('Location: http://mysite.com/');
    die();
} else {
//both keys correct. process Jquery data.
}
```

With this method, it would stop someone from manually browsing to `search_data.php` trying to do malicious things (I think?) and it would only allow Jquery to access it.

My question is, is there some sort of "hole" I'm not seeing here? Is this a good way to protect these kinds of web pages?

Comment: The client has access to everything that you have access to with javascript. If you use javascript to get the session variable and pass it, so can the client. If you are looking for session variables set by php, the client can send a request to your server from your page that has those same session variables. They don't even have to be aware of the session variables. All this does is prevents users from posting to your .php file using server-side code on a different domain. They can still do it from your domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anyone can simulate any HTTP request, so this method is not reliable. In this case he could forge a first HTTP request to initiate the session, store the cookie that the PHP script returned and reuse it to forge a second HTTP request passing along the cookie and the verification keys that he obtained from the first request.

Answer (score 1):

What sort of malicious things?  I'm guessing search_data.php links to a database?  It would be good to protect that script in particular to the least amount of access necessary.  You could use a database user that has only read access to your tables on search_data.php and that would minimize security threats a little bit.

Bottom line is the more potential damage a malicious user could do the more you need to protect your page and resources.

[OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) is a great resource for learning potential security threats and how to mitigate them.

Comment: Yeah it connects to a database but with read only privileges. I will check out this link, thanks.

Comment: @user1093634 - check out https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet in particular.  Because you're using a read-only account, the threat from a database perspective is much lower except that sensitive data might be viewed (if that's even a possibility).  If there's no sensitive data, then potential threats are much lower.